# tidyr join an ID table with main table across multiple columns

Tags: r, join, indexing, tidyr

This seems like a very basic operation, but my searches are not finding a simple solution.
As an example of what I am trying to do, consider the following two data frames from a database.
First an ID table that assigns an index to a color name:

```
ColorID <- tibble(ID = c(1:4), Name = c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black"))

ColorID
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID Name 
  <int> <chr>
1     1 Red  
2     2 Green
3     3 Blue 
4     4 Black
```

Next some table that points to these color indexes (instead of storing text strings):

```
Widgets <- tibble(Front = c(1,3,4,2,1,1), Back = c(4,4,3,3,1,2), 
                  Top = c(4,3,2,1,2,3), Bottom = c(1,2,3,4,3,2))
Widgets
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Front  Back   Top Bottom
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     4     4      1
2     3     4     3      2
3     4     3     2      3
4     2     3     1      4
5     1     1     2      3
6     1     2     3      2
```

Now I just want to join the two tables to substitute the index values with the actual color names, so what I want is:

```
Joined <- tibble(Front = c("Red", "Blue", "Black", "Green", "Red","Red"),
                 Back = c("Black", "Black", "Blue","Blue", "Red", "Green"),
                 Top = c("Black","Blue", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Blue"),
                 Bottom = c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black", "Blue","Green"))
Joined
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Front Back  Top   Bottom
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 Red   Black Black Red   
2 Blue  Black Blue  Green 
3 Black Blue  Green Blue  
4 Green Blue  Red   Black 
5 Red   Red   Green Blue  
6 Red   Green Blue  Green
```

I've tried many iterations with no success, what I thought would work is something like:

```
J <- Widgets %>% inner_join(ColorID, by = c(. = "ID"))
```

I can tackle this column by column by using one variable at a time, e.g.

```
J <- Widgets %>% inner_join(ColorID, by = c("Front" = "ID"))
```

Which doesn't replace "Front", but instead creates a new "Name" column. Seems like there has to be a simple solution to this though. Thanks.

Comment: Is performance at scale a consideration for you?  Or are all your tables "tame" in size?

Comment: They are relatively small, like in the 1000's of rows and 10's of columns.

Comment: Then the `pivot`ing [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68005063) by Karthik should perform sufficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for join functions:

```
library(dplyr)

ColorID <- tibble(ID = c(1:4), Name = c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black"))
# reorder so that row number and ID are different
ColorID <- ColorID[c(2, 1, 4, 3), ] 

Widgets <- tibble(Front = c(1,3,4,2,1,1), Back = c(4,4,3,3,1,2), 
                  Top = c(4,3,2,1,2,3), Bottom = c(1,2,3,4,3,2))

check_id <- function(col){
  ColorID$Name[match(col, ColorID$ID)]
}

Widgets %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), check_id))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Front Back  Top   Bottom
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 Red   Black Black Red   
2 Blue  Black Blue  Green 
3 Black Blue  Green Blue  
4 Green Blue  Red   Black 
5 Red   Red   Green Blue  
6 Red   Green Blue  Green
```

(Edited) What I'm doing with dplyr and mutate is matching the numbers on `Widgets` with the number on the `ColorID$ID` column. This provides me with the row on the ColorID data frame I need for extracting the name.

Comment: This would fail if the `ID` is not the same as the row number in `ColorID`?

Comment: Just tested it, and it **would indeed fail** if the `ID` is not the same as the row number in `ColorID`!  For example, if we replace `4` with `5` in `ID` — like so `ColorID <- tibble(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 5), ...)` — and also in `Widgets`, we will get `NA` rather than `"Black"` throughout the result.

Comment: Yes, I was using the provided ID. I'm editing my answer now to adapt the code.

Comment: I ended up using this solution because it was easier to deal with NA values in the dataset. There may be options to set in Karthik's solution that would solve this, but without any additional modifications, you get lists of different lengths when NA values are present and un-nesting fails.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Widgets %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  inner_join(ColorID, by = c('value' = 'ID')) %>% select(-value) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Name) %>% unnest(everything())
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Front Back  Top   Bottom
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 Red   Black Black Red   
2 Blue  Black Blue  Green 
3 Black Blue  Green Blue  
4 Green Blue  Red   Black 
5 Red   Red   Green Blue  
6 Red   Green Blue  Green
```

Comment: It seems to work perfectly despite the fact that it give a warning about the output containing list-cols. This does not happen, all output columns are character types. So, thanks!

Comment: You can add  `values_fn=list` into the `pivot_wider()`-function to suppress this warning.